# Steam user interface display problem

Tags: steam

I've been using steam on windows 8 for a while now and it's been fine. However all of a sudden it's displaying weirdly.

The game library has game's screenshots/image background overlapping the game list in details view.

Many dialog boxes appear very small with no UI elements showing, or with all elements on top of each-other.

Has anyone had this before? Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Steam updated recently. Its Win8 testing might not have been thorough. File a bug?

Comment: How do I submit a bug? If it's through the UI that might now work. :D Their forums seem to be offline for maintenance currently too.

Comment: *might not work

Answer (score 2):

A re-install of steam did the trick.

As I couldn't use the UI to backup my games first I was a little unsure but the following worked for me:

1. For each of your game libraries move the steamapps folder to somewhere else.
2. Uninstall steam and re-install it fresh (download latest from website).
3. Log in and set up your game library locations as they were before.
4. Close steam and move the steamapps folders back to their respective library locations (I didn't overwrite files where they were recreated by steam).
5. Restart steam.

When I restarted steam it found all games in all libraries including those partially downloaded fine.